# Magento tries to load resources from non existing folder pub/static/version1562677664/

Tags: magento2

I copied a working magento installation 1:1 from one server to another, but many important files can't get loaded and the site is broken.

I only deleted the folder `pub/static` and executed `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` on the clone after copying the clone to the new server.

[image]

I get this in my log (snippet):

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://entwicklung.m2/pub/static/version1562677664/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/css/styles-m.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

GET http://entwicklung.m2/pub/static/version1562677664/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/requirejs/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

...

(index):44 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
at (index):44
```

Comment: try to do for M2 basic commands.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: like upgrade,compile,deploy commands

Comment: Can you go into detail please?

Comment: check with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do with code

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0
```

than update your `.htaccess` file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /pub/static
    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

then execute next command to clear a configuration cache:

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: I tried it, but magento still tries to load the files from the non existing folder `pub/static/version1562677664/`. I even disabled cache.

Comment: please rename static folder, than put the commands.

Comment: I tried it, the error stays

Comment: can you please check pub/static/version1562677664 and inspect elements css url version both are same ?

Comment: The folder pub/static/version1562677664 does not exist.. only adminhtml, frontend and deployed_version.txt are inside pub/static

Comment: please check with my answer, i updated.

Comment: Now I get a big text with **404 error: Page not found.**

Comment: possible to send screenshot.